# Continuous and differentiable function

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Suppose $F : [a, b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous, differentiable on $(a, b)$ and $ab > 0$. Show that for some $c \in (a, b)$ the following holds:

$$\frac{aF(b)-bF(a)}{a-b} = F(c) - cF'(c) $$

Comment: same as this off-site example https://www.math24.net/cauchys-mean-value-theorem/#example1

Answer (score 1):

Use [Cauchy's mean value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem#Cauchy's_mean_value_theorem). Define $f, g : [a, b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ by $f(x) = \frac{F(x)}{x}$ and $g(x)=\frac{1}{x}$. These are well-defined since $ab>0$. Observe that $$ \frac{aF(b)-bF(a)}{a-b} = \frac{ f(b)-f(a) } {g(b)-g(a)}$$

By the theorem, there exists $c \in (a, b)$ such that $$ \frac{f(b)-f(a)}{g(a)-g(b)}=\frac{f'(c)}{g'(c)}$$
(Check that $g'(c) \neq 0 $ from $ab >0$ $(\therefore c \neq 0) $, and that $g(b) \neq g(a)$)

Equivalently, $$ \frac{f(b)-f(a)}{\frac{1}{b} - \frac{1}{a}} = \frac{\frac{F'(c)-cF(c)}{c^2} }{-\frac{1}{c^2}}=F(c)-cF'(c)$$

Now the claim follows.